# Solve the area on quadrant one given by the two curves

Tags: definite-integrals, area

$x^2+y^2=9$ and $ 4x^2+3y^2=36$

I'm having difficulties solving this, but I was told the answer is $\frac{3}{4}\pi$

However, when I equate the two and get $x = 3$ I try to solve them but can't get the correct answer after integration. I was thinking if these are like $2$ circle problem and then apply definite integrals but then again I can't get the correct answer.

Comment: Add your solution so that we can see where's the problem.

Comment: The correct answer seems to be $\frac{3}{4}(-3+2\sqrt{3}) \pi.$

Comment: With respect to the ellipse $4x^2+3y^2=36$, the answer for the area is not $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, rather the area is $\frac{(6\sqrt{3}-9)\pi}{4}$. If we insist that the area is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, then we change the ellipse into $$16x^2+9y^2=144.$$ What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

You want area between a circle and ellipse in first quadrant

$$ a=3,\, b= \sqrt12,\, A = \frac14 \pi a ( b-a)= \frac{(2\sqrt{3}-3)\, 3\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

The required region (shaded portion) is given below:
[image]

The upper curve is given by $y=\sqrt{\frac{36-4x^2}{3}}$ and the lower curve is $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$. Thus, the area is given by
$$A=\int_{0}^3\sqrt{\frac{36-4x^2}{3}}dx-\frac{\pi 3^2}{4}$$
Using Wolfram Alpha, 
$$\int_{0}^3\sqrt{\frac{36-4x^2}{3}}dx=\frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}$$ but as you have noted the integral is $\frac{\text{area of the ellipse}}{4}=\frac{\pi(3)\sqrt{12}}{4}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}$. Hence, the required area is
$$A=\frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}-\frac{9\pi}{4}=\frac{(6\sqrt{3}-9)\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

$x^2+y^2=9$

and $ 4x^2+3y^2=36$

Divide by 36 above equation,

$\frac{x^2}9 + \frac{y^2}{12} = 1$

So first equation is circle and other is ellipse.

**Edit 1 -**

I am checking on wolframalpha [you can see.](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D9+and+4x%5E2%2B3y%5E2%3D36&x=0&y=0)

**Edit 2 -**

[image: page 1]

As you can see area bounded by x axis and both curves is equal to area bounded by circle.

Comment: I know that the area of ellipse if $pi(a)(b)$ and that a=3 and b=$\sqrt12$ however do I have to add it to the circle? but that doesn't make 3/4 pi

Comment: So you mean to say I have to minus the area of the ellipse to the area of the circle right/

Comment: You can put your solution here.

Comment: $\frac{pi}{4}(a)(b)$ where a=3 and b = $\sqrt12$ then area of a circle $pi(r^2)/4$ where r = 3. However I don't get 3/4pi

Comment: I still don't get it, if i graph it It looks like I just need to minus it, however I still can't get the 3/4 pi

Comment: In graph both intersect at x = 3 and the area bounded by both is area bounded by circle in first quadrant.

Comment: where you able to get 3/4 pi?

Comment: No I able to get 9/4 pi. But when I saw wolframalpha's output. I am confused.

Comment: how did you solve 9/4 pi?

Comment: Area bounded by circle between 0 to 3.

Comment: Are you sure with the answer? Mine is $\frac{(6\sqrt{3}-9)\pi}{4}$.

Comment: same here gensan. since it's quadrant one so just minus the two right? I think they gave me a wrong problem, what do you think?

Comment: GenSan I am getting the same answer if I subtract these two.